# "Sorry, unexpected internal error" after installing Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 7 on PC

Tags: system-installation, updates, 13.04

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 to a dual boot with the previously installed Windows 7.

During the first installation attempt, the install froze. I then restarted my PC and attempted to install again, and it worked this time.

After logging in, when I tried to launch Software Updater, it froze again, and then nothing showed up. After a minute or so, it gave me an error:

```
Sorry, unexpected internal error
```

Comment: did you split your harddrive in separate partitions before installing Ubuntu? sometimes making partitions during intallation returns problems

Comment: yeah... 8 gb partition.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me when i had installed 12.04 , haven't tried 13.04 yet though . Check your system requirements first that if it does suit the the version , then move forward . I had to downgrade to 10.04 for the very same reason .

Comment: Then i guess, i too will have to downgrade it. Sh*T!

Comment: Can u let me know your system configuration ?